# Comparing contents of char array at specific index to char literal - cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I have a really simple question here, just not sure what to use to solve it.

I'm trying to write a program in c++ that uses an explicit stack to check whether the contents of a character array contains parentheses that are balanced.

I haven't implemented the stack yet. My question is how to go through the character array and compare the contents at each index position to char literals.

Basically the logic of the problem is that you traverse the char array one pos at a time, and every time you get an opening paren, you push that char onto the stack, and every time you get a closing paren, you compare it to the char on top of the stack, and if they're the same, you pop the stack and continue traversing the char array. If you get a closing paren, and either the stack is empty, or the char on top doesn't match the closing paren (i.e. curly brace instead of square bracket), the char array is not balanced.

So I have a for loop to traverse the char array, and the first thing I need to do is write an if statement, which basically says: if the element at position 'i' in the array is "(" or if it's "{" or if it's "[", push it onto the stack.

But I don't know how to compare the contents of a certain index position to a char literal.

Here's what I tried to do:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    stack<char> S;
    char* parens = "{()()}";
    int len = strlen(parens);

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(parens[i] == "(" || parens[i] == "{" || parens[i] == "["){
            S.push(parens[i]);
        } else { // etc
```

Visual studio didn't like that if statement. It says it can't compare "char" with "const char *."

I also tried using strcmp(parens[i], "(/{/[") == 0 , and it didn't like that either. I have to use a character array instead of a string since I need to traverse it using an index pos, but I'm not sure how to compare these.

I would really appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: You're trying to compare a character to a string, don't do that.

Comment: can I just typecast it to char, like say if(parens[i] == (char)"("){

Comment: I just want to know the correct way to do this:) i could typecast it but that just seems inelegant and I'm sure there's a better/ "proper" way, I just don't know what it is

Comment: Don't cast it, it won't work. Just compare a character to a character.

Comment: Use std::string. Use chars '(' instead of strings "(".

Comment: Casting should be among the last resorts, especially the C-style cast. That sucker is The God Hammer. It will make the object fit, no matter how ill suited. It can make the compiler think a circle is a square and the program will misbehave at runtime as a result. You have to be absolutely freaking certain before using a C-style cast. If you're guessing, you'll almost always be wrong, and you just stripped away the first line of defense against the resulting bugs: The compiler.

Comment: You can index a string the same way as a character array and it's safer because you can know the length at any time. `string s = "foo"; s[2] = 'b'; etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement compares to string literals. String literals are all in double quotes like these: `"{"`, `"("`, and `"["`. Char literals are all in single quotes like these: `'{'`, `'('`, and `'['`.

Try this code sample. Instead of comparing a literal string to a char, it compares a literal char to a char. I also added `const` in front of your string literal declarations because some C++ compilers insist such variables be `const char *` instead of just `char *`.

```
int main(){
    stack<char> S;
    const char* parens = "{()()}";
    const int len = strlen(parens);

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if ( ( parens[i] == '(' ) || ( parens[i] == '{' ) || ( parens[i] == '[' ) {
            S.push(parens[i]);
        } else { // etc
```

Comment: That's it! The single vs double quotes were my problem. I'm happy it was just a syntactic fix! Thank you for teaching me the correct cpp syntax for this!